# Does a locally projective scheme over an affine scheme embed into projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

**Definition.** A morphism of schemes $f\colon X\to S$ is called *locally projective* if there is an open covering $S=\bigcup_{j\in J}V_j$, integers $n(j)\geq 0$, and closed embeddings $f^{-1}(V_j)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{n(j)}\times V_j$ over $V_j$.

(This is equivalent to what's used in the Stacks Project, cf. [[Tag 01WB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WB)]).

Let $A$ be a ring, $S=\operatorname{Spec}A$, $f\colon X\to S$ a locally projective morphism. Does there exist an integer $n\geq 0$ and a closed embedding $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n\times S$? This is trivially the case if $A$ is local.